# Is the speed-of-light delay a limiting factor in the design of today's microprocessors?

Tags: electric-circuits, speed-of-light, classical-electrodynamics

My computer's processor works at 2.5 GHz, so light only has time to travel 12 cm in a vacuum per clock cycle.  I believe that most solids have a dielectric constant that slows down the speed of light by at least a factor of 3 or so, so electric signals would only have time to travel ~4 cm through the wires in my computer per clock cycle.  That's about the size of the microprocessor itself, so it seems like the signals would need the entire clock cycle just to propagate across the microprocessor.  And obviously that's not counting the time it takes for the transistors to change state, the chip to read from and write to RAM, etc.  (In fact, my RAM chips are significantly longer than 4 cm.)  So it seems like microprocessor operations should be in the ultrarelativistic regime where you'd need to keep careful track of all the light cones, etc. in order to make sure that the different parts of the chip are in causal contact with each other.  So why haven't I ever heard of this being an issue in microprocessor design?

Comment: Clock distribution is a major problem in high speed u-proc. But it is more a question of capacitance and resistance than purely 'c'

Comment: As far as I know there are currently no commercial optical chips

Comment: @AlbertAspect I don't know of any either, but the speed of light also limits the speed at which electrical signals can travel down the conductive traces on a circuit board.

Comment: Keep in mind the size of the actual processor is usually much smaller than the size of the chassis used to house it.